# modulo operation vectorization

Tags: c, intel, vectorization

there is a cycle:

```
 long a* = new long[32];
 long b* = new long[32];
 double c* = new double[32];
 double d = 3.14159268;
  //set a, b and c arrays
  //.....
  for(int i = 0; i < 32; i ++){
    d+= (a[i] % b[i])/c[i];
  }
```

how i can implement this cycle using Intel C++ vectoriation capabilities (e.g. #pragma simd or sse- instructions)?

If i write:

```
  #pragma simd reduction(+:c)
  for(int i = 0; i < 32; i ++){
    d+= (a[i] % b[i])/c[i];
  }
```

then speed does not increase :(

Comment: Why are you casting the results to `double`?

Comment: That code won't compile. Maybe you meant `(double)(a[i] % b[i])`?

Comment: @us2012: this result must be double. Example corrected for demonstrative.

Comment: @interjay yes, sorry, example corrected.

Comment: Have you added the appropriate compiler switches?

Comment: @Klas Lindbäck: yes, of course

Answer (score 5):

The Intel 64 and IA-32 architectures do not have a vectorized integer divide or remainder/modulo instruction, so there is no way to vectorize general remainder operations in hardware while using integer arithmetic.

There are some floating-point vector divide instructions. The double-precision divide (DIVPD) is not truly vectorized in processors I checked; it takes twice as long as a single-precision divide, so the hardware implements it by using one divider serially (and not even pipelined to any significant degree).

If single-precision suffices, you might be able to get some boost from using the single-precision vector divide (DIVPS), but you would have to deal with floating-point rounding and take care to ensure you got the desired result. Using the approximate-reciprocal instruction (RCPPS) with the Newton-Raphson might be faster than using DIVPS but will require even more care in the design.

Comment: What about __m128i _mm_div_epi32 (__m128i a, __m128i b) for integer division?

Comment: @Bogi: This answer was written in 2013.

Comment: Yes, I see, it might have been correct at the time, but it is not correct anymore. Can you update it? Modulo is still not supported though :(